# Data from Access DB wont load into textbox

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm trying to load one string data from a local Access database, when I press a button, the data won't load and I'm getting the following error:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

```cs
string strProvider = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\training\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\LucruCilindrii.accdb";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strProvider);
con.Open();
string passingValue = "SELECT NumarDeOreLucrate FROM Ore_lucru_Cilindrii WHERE DiametruSuperior = " + textBox4.Text;
OleDbCommand cmmd = new OleDbCommand(passingValue, con);
OleDbDataReader reader1 = cmmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader1.Read())
{
    textBox1.Text = (reader1["NumarDeOreLucrate"].ToString());
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: can you try 

 string passingValue = "SELECT NumarDeOreLucrate FROM Ore_lucru_Cilindrii WHERE DiametruSuperior = '" + textBox4.Text + "'";  (note the extra quotes that surround textBox4.Text

Comment: Consider using [prepared statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.prepare)

Comment: What @barbsan said, obligatory [xkcd reference](https://xkcd.com/327/).